# Display adapter or other hardware, driver maybe?

Tags: nvidia

I have installed on a BIOSTAR 68S+ Motherboard with NVIDIA MCP61-mcp61-86 video adapter.   CPU AMD 9100e 1.8ghz 
The install went flawlessly.  I experienced sudden change in screen output to diagonal zigzag lines the color of the previous displayed items.  seems random to this user.  occurs while sitting on home screen,  or while using software, teases you into thinking its going to be ok, then not.

I ran several hardware test programs for video, memory and cpu.  no errors in hours of operation.

I thought it was a problem with ubuntu drivers so I installed a different linux package,  untangle.   it did the same video zizag which could not be recovered.  I wonder if similar debian base software issue,   I want the UBUNTU do I need a different MoBo?  I am not savvy enough to change drivers if that is the issue.   any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately Nvidia stopped supporting that old integrated chip a long time ago and consequently there are no alternative proprietary drivers for it. It either works with the current versions of the default `nouveau` driver or it doesn't and apparently the latter is true. Even so I would try with a lighter Ubuntu variant like Lubuntu.

Comment: Seems silly maybe based on costs but would a video card and disable the on-board work?  If so which cards might be compatible? ( chip-sets ) I wonder if there is a list somewhere.

Comment: Not silly... You can find a cheap second hand or even new PCI Express 2.0 x16 graphics card (preferably Nvidia) and the cheapest one you can find will be light-years away from the integrated chip in terms of performance (and will have support at least with legacy Nvidia drivers (or open-source if AMD).

Comment: And likely all it takes is to install the card. In most cases this automatically disables the onboard. But it's Biostar, who knows?

Comment: haha ,  my other box is ASUS,   you get what you pay for :)  I ordered a PCI card,  i will let you all know if it works.  DC

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for the card,  I played around with bios, pallet snoop , and other things that I figured were video related and the distortion stopped.   I rebooted a couple of times and it seemed stable.   browsed internet etc.  left it on and it was still on next morning.    Being curious I reset bios to defaults and low and behold it is still working so I do not know what the deal was ( or still is)  I am going to put the video card in when it gets here before I place in service but ...  I am sure its the driver/on-board chip set  since it did the same thing with untangle.   but for just a second I thought I was onto something.
DC